# Dropbox not linking on iPhone App Store (or ad hoc) build but works fine building from xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox

I link using this:

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
```

Works fine when building from xcode, and seems to work fine on app store and ad hoc builds, bringing up the dropbox app if installed or another view if it's not installed

```
[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]
```

returns true when building from xcode, but false when using ad hoc or app store build. Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you're not logged in on the device, only in the simulator.

Comment: I'm talking about testing on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have it. It's now working in my ad hoc builds. We'll see what happens when it gets approved. It seems the new version of the API requires you to handle the url on app open like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        // At this point you can start making API Calls. Login was successful
        [self doSomething];
    } else {
        // Login was canceled/failed.
    }
    return YES;
}
// Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
return NO;
```

}

I still have no idea why everything worked on my device in testing but not with ad hoc or app store builds, but it appears handling the openURL callback fixes this.